# Catch in Observable stops HTTP Calls from Observable.interval

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

```
Observable.interval(10000)
     .switchMap(() => this.http.get(url))
     .catch (err => Observable.empty())
     .subscribe(data => render(data))
```

Each 10 seconds we make an HTTP call. If an error happens, observable becomes completed, it doesn't make any calls anymore. How to prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct behavior, when a `complete` or `error` notification is sent observers unsubscribe and the chain is disposed.

You can use the `retry()` operator to resubscribe but it's hard to tell what is your goal from this brief description.

```
Observable.interval(10000)
    .switchMap(() => this.http.get(url))
    .retry()
    .subscribe(data => render(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

takeUntil() of observable.

RxJS implements the takeUntil operator. You can pass it either an Observable or a Promise that it will monitor for an item that triggers takeUntil to stop mirroring the source Observable.

for more info [click here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html#collapseRxJS)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let dataX = Observable.interval(10000)
 .switchMap(() => this.http.get(url));

let caught = dataX.catch(
Observable.return({
error: 'There was an error in http request'
}))

caught.subscribe((data) => { return render(data) },
// Because we catch errors now, `error` will not be executed
(error) => {console.log('error', error.message)}
 )
```

if you want you can put any condition  when the error comes like

```
if(!data[error]){
  render(data)
}
```

I hope that it helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable.interval(10000)
     .switchMap(() => this.http.get(url)
     .map(res => res.json())
     .catch (err => Observable.empty()))
     .subscribe(data => render(data))
```